# Filteration of Rows based on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called **`AssetTable`** which stores **AssetId**

I have another table called **`AssetBookTable`** which stores two fields **BookId** and **CurrentOperationsTax**

Another table **`AssetBook`** that stores **AssetId** and **BookId** as foriegn keys.

> Now, I have a situation in which I have to **filter records based on
> AssetBookTable.CurrentOperationsTax**

This, is what I am getting now,
[image: This is so far I have achieved]

And this, is what I want:
[image: This is what I want to achieve]

**

**The logic is that I want only one BookId per AssetId that has either Current/Operation/Tax for CurrentOperationsTax field.**

**

Here's the SQL fiddle written so far:

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3477/31)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your effort so far is `SELECT * FROM Course`? That fiddle has *none* of the tables *or* columns in your question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing Mike, I just corrected my path. That was something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple remove the `GROUP BY BookID`. But of course you then need to aggregate the BookID some how. Here using the MIN() function:

```
SELECT
   ab.AssetId
  ,MIN(ab.BookId) as BookID
  ,abt.CuurentOperationsTax
FROM
 AssetBook ab
JOIN AssetTable at ON at.AssetId = ab.AssetId
JOIN AssetBookTable abt ON abt.BookId = ab.BookId
GROUP BY 
   ab.AssetId
  ,abt.CuurentOperationsTax
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e3477/42

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the ROW_NUMBER approach.  It does require the use of a subquery.  In summary it is grouping the records by the CuurentOperationsTax number and ordering by book id and giving the row number for each grouping.  Then in the outer select I filter out how many I want for each grouping.  In this example just 1.

```
SELECT   AssetId
        ,BookId
        ,CuurentOperationsTax
        ,RowNum
FROM   (
        SELECT
           ab.AssetId
          ,ab.BookId
          ,abt.CuurentOperationsTax
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY abt.CuurentOperationsTax ORDER BY ab.BookId) AS RowNum
        FROM
         AssetBook ab
        JOIN AssetTable AT ON AT.AssetId = ab.AssetId
        JOIN AssetBookTable abt ON abt.BookId = ab.BookId
      ) AS b
WHERE b.RowNum = 1
```